# External table is not in the expected format asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel

i am trying to import and export Excel. Here is the process flow.. one user download the Excel and other user upload it. Excel is downloaded from one web apllication  and then uploaded to other web application.(where excel data is selected and performed different action)

**Code For downloading EXCEL**

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls")

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")
        'sets font
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>")
        'sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background, foreground, font height
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " + "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " + "style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'>")
        'am getting my grid's column headers
        Dim columnscount As Integer = GridView_Result.Columns.Count

        Dim Console As String = ""
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>")
        For Each column In dtEmp.Columns
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(column.ColumnName)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>")
        Next
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>")
        For Each row As DataRow In dtEmp.Rows
            'write in new row
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR style=background-color :#FFFFFF>")
            For i As Integer = 0 To dtEmp.Columns.Count - 1
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row(i).ToString())
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>")
            Next

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>")
        Next
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()

        Response.ClearContent()
```

Now I am able to download Excel but when i uploaded it and try to read it, It is given me "**External table is not in the expected format**" error but when i manually create any excel and try to upload and read that excel then it is working perfect and not giving any error

Code for reading EXCEL

```
var FilePATH = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/" + "DEMO.xls");
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string con = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Data Source={0};" +
                             "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePATH);



                con = String.Format(con, FilePATH);
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(con);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                //Get the name of First Sheet
                connExcel.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                connExcel.Close();

                //Read Data from First Sheet
                connExcel.Open();
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From  [" + SheetName + "]";
                oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                oda.Fill(dt);
                connExcel.Close();
```

And it will be good if you provide me answer without using any third party DLL  and production server have no office installed and it will not be installed in future. So i cannot use interlope also

when i open downloaded excel and saved it as "EXCEL 97-2003 Workbook" then this new excel is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Can you export only table tag and retry?

If you fill Excel manually it is surely in correct format, while the exported html can be interpreted not correctly.

I suggest to use ClosedXml (free and open source) even if you ask to not suggest third party dll